# Cargue Archivos CSV y Expresiones Regulares C# - Definir separador "," para números decimales

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, validación

Estoy realizando cargue masivo de información utilizando C#, para ello he definido un método que lea el archivo Csv

```
 public static DataTable ObtieneDatosCsv(String ruta, String archivo)
    {
        Regex.Replace(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ruta + archivo), ";", ","));

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ruta + archivo,
               Regex.Replace(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ruta + archivo), "  ", " "));

        string connectionStringCsv = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
          Source=" + ruta  + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1;\"";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringCsv);
            objConn.Open();
            OleDbCommand objCmdSelect =
             new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + archivo + "]", objConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
            objAdapter1.Fill(dt);
            objConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //Error Code
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

El problema de utilizar el controlador JET, es que este intenta asignarle a la columna un tipo de datos. Si una columna tiene datos mixtos, el método no genera error pero toma ese dato como un NULL. En el caso de números, JET es sensible al separador decimal, sino se escribe un numero con el separador decimal correcto, te dara un NULL. Intente usar el parametro IMEX para corregir el problema y no funciono.

Ahora estoy intendo constuir una expresión regular cuyas entradas validas sean números naturales o números decimales con separador ","

La expresión regular que he escrito es:

```
^[0-9,^\.]+$
```

Acepto números y su separador decimal **","** (el que he definido en configuración regional e idioma) e intento excluir con **^** el punto **"/."** para asegurarme que el usuario digite solo números con separador ","

Si escribo:

^[0-9]+$

Aceptará entradas con separador "."

Si escribo

```
     ^[0-9,]+$
```

Aceptará entradas con separadores "." y ","

Es algo sencillo, pero no consigo que funcione, alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Comment: _¿Que formato de numeración es valido?_ y _¿Qué formato de numeración es invalido?_

Comment: Las etiquetas no deben incluirse en el título. Véase [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo deben usarse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)?

Comment: ¿Existe una necesidad muy específica de usar `JET` en conjunto con `DataTable`? Pregunto esto debido a que el consumo de recursos de un `DataTable` es mayor en comparación con Linq y listas genéricas.

Comment: No entiendo que tratas de hacer en tu código. Por lo que veo primero buscas las apariciones de caracteres punto y coma (;) y las reemplazas por comas (,). Y después buscas espacios en blanco y los reemplazas por espacios en blanco???? 
¿Y dónde quieres aplicar la expresión regular de los números decimales?

Answer (score 1):

No tienes porque indicarle que no sea punto si ya indicas que los caracteres deben ser dígitos o comas.

Por otra parte la expresión regular debería indicar que el número debería estar formado por:

- Uno o más dígitos
- Seguidos opcionalmente por una coma y uno o más
  dígitos

Algo así:

```
 ^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: Pero esta expresión obliga a que el número siempre tenga un separador ",". Si escribes un numero sin separador entonces no funciona.

Comment: @DiegoFernandoBarriosOlmos: Edita tu pregunta para clarificar cuáles son las entradas válidas y y cuáles no. Una forma de hacerlo es incluir ejemplos de entradas válidas e inválidas.

Comment: No. Todo lo que está encerrado entre paréntesis (el separador decimal y los dígitos decimales) está afectado por el cuantificador '?' que indica que puede aparecer una o ninguna vez.

Comment: Si funciona. Pero no escapa cuando la expresión lleva puntos como separador. Ej: 10.14, 15.9

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no "escapa"? Esos ejemplos no van a ser válidos para la expresión regular que pongo.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva la estoy testeando y no funciona, la expresión acepta números con separador "," y con separador "."

Comment: Revisa tu código. El problema tiene que estar en otra parte: http://regexr.com/3g0qi

Comment: @AsierVillanueva, Si el problema esta en la lectura que realiza el Driver JET. Elimina los "." antes de realizar la validación